# Не находится элемент по xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Я прохожусь по ссылкам. На каждой из них есть эелемент, который мне необходимо забрать, забираю я его при помощи xpath, выглядит это следующим образом:

```
def get_name(browser):

    """ Получить название """

        while True:

            try:

                name = browser.find_element( 
                    By.XPATH,
                    '//h1[@class="product-title"]'
                ).text

                return name

            except Exception as e:

                print(e)
                time.sleep(.5)


for link in list_links:

    browser = self.get_configured_browser()     # Получаю настроенный браузер
    browser.get(link)                           # Перехожу по ссылке
    browser.maximize_window()                   # Открываю браузер во весь экран

    name = get_name(browser)                    # Забрать имя со страницы
```

Вместо названия мне возвращается ошибка `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//h1[@class="product-title"]"}`
Но я не понимаю почему.

В открытом браузере, в инструментах разработчика вставлял xpath и у меня подсвечивался искомый элемент.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ставил задержку, `browser.implicitly_wait(10)`  и `time.sleep(10)`, также не находит, на всякий случай посмотрел нет ли лишних окон `browser.window_handles` - нет. Меня способ по поиску элемента - `browser.find_element_by_css_selector('h1.product-title')` и все равно не находит.

Ссылка на страницу - https://pay.hotmart.com/B57915273M?checkoutMode=0&bid=1629216829630

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_visible((By.XPATH, "//h1[@class="product-title"]")))
```

Будет ждать пока этот элемент не появится. Если этого не случится, то попробуйте установить юзер-агент соответствующий вашему браузеру.

Comment: а wait откуда импортитровать?

Comment: А как насчет погуглить?